# How to set cookies on a specific domain using pickle and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, automation, pickle

I'm busy creating an automation tool for a certain website but can't seem to find an option to store cookies between two different runs. The main problem is that the website consists of [www.website.com/beforelogin](http://www.website.com/beforelogin) and [www.website.com/afterlogin](http://www.website.com/afterlogin), every other url is just being redirected to one of these depending on whether you're logged in or not. Since there is no 'overlapping url'/'dummy url' where I can save cookies the first time I log in manually and load them every other time from then on, I don't really see how to fix this. This is my code for saving and loading the cookies.

```
    def save_cookies(self):
        self.browser.get("http://www.website.com") # will be redirected to www.website.com/afterlogin at where it will save the cookies
        pickle.dump(self.browser.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))

    def load_cookies(self):
        self.browser.get("http://www.website.com") # will be redirected to www.website.com/beforelogin at where it will load the cookies
        if not os.path.isfile("cookies.pkl"):
            return False

        cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
        print("loading cookies")
        for cookie in cookies:
            print("Adding cookies")
            self.browser.add_cookie(cookie)

        self.refresh()
```

The solution of finding a common dummy url as talked about in [How to set a cookie to a specific domain in selenium webdriver with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919525/how-to-set-a-cookie-to-a-specific-domain-in-selenium-webdriver-with-python) is, as explained above, not really a solution.

Solutions like this one [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain while executing tests in Django with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877561/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidcookiedomainexception-message-invalid-cookie) isn't an option either since there is no same url for the before and after login where cookies are saved and loaded.